# SublimeText Typescript Format on Save

Tags: typescript, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Using Microsoft's [Typescript plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin) for sublime, I can format a file using `^T ^F` as mentioned in [features](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin#features).

Is they a way to run this command automatically when saving a file? I'm after something akin to Sublime-HTMLPrettify [Beautify on Save](https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-HTMLPrettify#beautify-on-save) feature.

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is likely an existing plugin on [PackgeControl](http://packagecontrol.io/) that allows you to do something like this, although I'm not aware of any off the top of my head and the site is not responsive at the moment.

In the meantime, simplistically you can accomplish this via some simple plugin code:

```python
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class FormatTypescriptOnSave(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_pre_save(self, view):
        if "TypeScript" in view.settings().get("syntax"):
            view.run_command("typescript_format_document")
```

To use this, select `Tools > Developer > New Plugin...` from the menu, then replace the entire contents of the template document with this code, and save it (name doesn't matter, only the extension).

This catches a save that's about to happen and runs the appropriate command, so long as the current file is a TypeScript file, as determined by the currently set syntax.

Comment: That's a great help, though I struggled getting it to load at first. I saved the file in ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/TypeScript-OnSave/TypeScript-OnSave.py. Presuming it could have gone anywhere in the Packages folder?

Comment: Yep, technically anywhere under `Packages` is fine. Some people put things like that in their `User` package (that's the default location suggested to you if you follow the steps above) but that's just down to preference regarding how you like to lay your changes out.

Comment: Thanks a ton this is a really awesome piece of information.

Comment: I've saved it in user, but it isn't formatting my typescript files? Is there way to specify formatting?

Comment: You can check the Sublime console (`View > Show Console`) to see if there are any error messages displayed at startup when the plugin is loaded. If there's not, the only other reason I can think for it not working would be if you don't have the Microsoft TypeScript package installed.

Comment: How to pass settings though?

Comment: @caub what settings?

Comment: @OdatNurd like `"javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBraces": false,` I've found a way: https://gist.github.com/caub/bc4ab4a7dc2978837fbc3fcc8a823504 but it's not practical

Answer (score 3):

I am using [`HTML-CSS-JS Prettify`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML-CSS-JS%20Prettify) plugin.

After installing the package, open `HTMLPrettify.sublime-settings` under the menu `Preferences > Package Settings > HTML/CSS/JS Prettify > Plugin Options - User` and paste this setting below:

```json
{
    "format_on_save": true,
    "global_file_rules":
    {
        "js":
        {
            "allowed_file_extensions": ["js", "jsx", "ts"],
            "allowed_file_syntaxes": ["javascript", "typescript", "ecma", "react", "babel"],
            "disallowed_file_patterns": []
        },
    }
}
```